# How do I set the Vertex color from a loop?

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to instantiate multiple objects and set their Vertex Color from a predefined Color List. For some reason it always applies the last color to all of the objects.

What am I missing here?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling *Deep Copy* option in the *Object Instancer* node solves the problem. Vertex colors are property of meshes, thus in order to have different colors for different objects, their meshes have to be independent (Different copies of the source mesh), which is what *Deep Copy* do.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I only had to check Deep Copy in the Object Instancer Node.